# Find Density Function, Cumulative Distribution, and Expected Value given only Interval

Tags: probability, statistics

Do not have answers to this problem
Please let me know if there are mistakes

Let Y be a random variable that is uniformly distributed on the interval $[2,4]$.

a) What is $f_Y(Y)$?

b) Give an explicit formula for the cumulative distribution function $F_Y(Y)$

c) Find $E(Y)$

Attempt:

a)

> Using definition:
>
> $f(x; A, B) = \begin{cases} {1\over B-A}, & A \le x \le B \\ 
> 0,  &\text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$

$$f_Y(Y) =
\begin{cases}
{1\over 2}, & 2 \le Y \le 4 \\ 
0,  &\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$
b)

> Using definition:
>
> $F(X) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$

\begin{align}
F(Y) &= \int_{2}^Y f(t) dt \\\\
 &= \int_{2}^Y {1 \over 2} dt \\\\
 &= {Y-2 \over 2}
\end{align}

$F(Y) =$
\begin{cases}
{0}, &\text{Y < 2} \\
{Y-2 \over 2}, &\text{$2$ ≤ $Y$ ≤ $4$} \\
{1}, &\text{Y > 4} \\
\end{cases}

c)

> Using definition:
>
> $E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx$

\begin{align}
E(Y) &= \int_{2}^4 Yf(Y) dY \\\\
&= \int_{2}^4 Y{1 \over 2} dY \\\\
&= 12
\end{align}

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part c,

$$\int_2^4 \frac{y}{2} \, dy = \frac{y^2}{4}\bigg|_{y=2}^{y=4} = \frac{12}{4}=3$$

Notice that in general, for uniform distribution on interval $[a,b]$, the expected value would be $\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Minor comment about notation: We to write $F_Y(\color{blue}{y})=Pr(Y \leq y)$ rather than $F_Y(Y)$.